# ERROR MESSAGE: E Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: 11.04, installation

I've been getting this exact error message since I installed Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal 64-bit on 10/09.

I haven't installed any updates, so it can't be that, since its the first thing that pops up.

What I've tried:

My Ubuntu 11.04 (Oct 9th, 64-Bit) fresh install sends me this message when I try to execute the following commands

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock 
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Message:

`rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory`

Here is what happens one minute after I installed Ubuntu (Regluar-not LTS version) via the ISO file downloaded directly from Ubuntu.com.

(I try to install VLC media player, after attempting to install Ubuntu Restricted Extras).

Here's what it says:

(Updates not installed yet at this point)

"An handleable error occurred"

There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks.

Now,I have tried to check to see if there is a VITAL program holding the lock, but I'm a LINUX NEWBIE. Everything says that it's dormant, so what's holding the lock?

(I've also tried to update the kernel version, but that has never worked.)

PLEASE, if there is someone out there that knows what they are talking about, help me.

Comment: ... and edit into your question the output of `sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock`